# Warning: Undefined variable $_SESSION

Tags: php

tengo un Warning: Undefined variable $_SESSION in C:\xampp... en mi página y no se como arreglarlo o que me falta, no soy programador, agradecería cualquier ayuda/pista.

Son 3 páginas en php, blog.php, un include\Elusuario.php que incluyo en el blog.php y un include\conectado.php que incluyo en include\Elusuario.php .

Os unifico el código de cada una.

````
//Fragmento de la página blog, si está logueado el usuario ve los mensajes, si no ve un link a logueate
var_dump ($_SESSION); //comprobar errores
if ((isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) && ($_SESSION['loggedin']!= ""))

//Página includes\Elusuario.php    
       if (isset ($_SESSION['loggedin'])){ include "Conectado.php"; }

//Página includes\Conectado.php 
echo "". $_SESSION['name']; // Mostramos el username almacenado en name

/* La página conectado.php avisa con:

  Warning: Undefined variable $_SESSION in C:\xampp\htdocs\DavAr\includes\Conectado.php on line 1
  Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\DavAr\includes\Conectado.php on line 1 */
?>```
````

Comment: ¿Has iniciado la sesión con `session_start()` antes de manipular la variable `$_SESSION`?

Comment: Gracias, resuelto. Ha si es, no iniciaba sesión, me fie ya que session start(); está en includes\Elusuario y me llevó a pensar que no hacia falta inicializarla en cada página php que interactue con un usuario o con $_SESSION